# Graphics, smooth shading and normals

Tags: vector, graphics, geometry

I'm trying to achieve smooth shading of triangles in my graphics program, however I'm currently stuck on how to do it exactly, I've got two options.

**Option 1: (per vector)**

1. Create a "zero" Vector.
2. Add the **non-normalized** normal of every incident triangle to the created vector.
3. Scale the resulting vector by `1 / incidentTriangleCount`.
4. Return the **normalized** version of the resulting vector.

**Option 2: (per vector)**

1. Create a "zero" Vector.
2. Add the **normalized** normal of every incident triangle to the created vector.
3. Scale the resulting vector by `1 / incidentTriangleCount`.
4. Return the **non-normalized** version of the resulting vector.

Both approaches are giving me different results and I don't really know which one to take, can anyone give me advice on this?

Comment: If you can assign normals only to triangles (not vertices), than you cant do smooth shading.

Comment: @athabaska I currently have for every triangle (face) one normal. And per vertex I want to take the average of all triangles (faces) incident to that vertex, isn't that what I need to do?

Comment: Oh, thats how it's done, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Always work with normalized normals. Thus your two options will merge in single one :)

Besides, you have to be careful when using "every" incident triangle, because in this case you will have your entire model smoothed, which is not good. E.g. a model of pencil that actually have edges will look like a rounded one. Implement a treshold, i.e. only consider triangles, which normals have relatively small angle beetween them.